# What is more polar?

Tags: bond, electronegativity

Is the bond $\ce{Cs-F}$ more polar or $\ce{C-F}$ ? I am not sure because I thought $\ce{Cs-F}$ is classified as an ionic bond, and $\ce{C-F}$ as a polar covalent one. Based on electronegativity values, $\ce{Cs-F}$ has the highest electronegativity difference, so would that be the most polar bond?

Comment: Also the ranges are usually .5<x<2 = polar

Comment: and > 2 electronegativity difference is ionic

Comment: Instead of posting follow-up comments you may wish to [edit] your question.

Comment: We don't even have to look at the electronegativity difference. Any ionic bond is more polar than any covalent bond.

Answer (score 0):

$\ce{Cs-F}$ bond is more polar than $\ce{C-F}$ bond.
Electronegativity (rather electropositivity if I may say for $\ce{Cs}$) is $0.69$ . Electronegativity for $\ce{C}$ is $2.55$ and for $\ce{F}$ is $3.98$. These values are according to Pauling scale.

As you have correctly mentioned in your question, the bond for which the difference in electronegativity of bonding atoms is large, that bond is classified as ionic.

(Difference $> 2$ is classified as ionic and if $< 2$ is classified as covalent.)

Comment: As a doubt I would like to ask this : _Can we call ionic bonds polar covalent bonds ?_

Comment: No. You can't call ionic bonds as polar covalent bonds. The extent of the effect of the Columb force is different in both cases.

Comment: Since you can't call ionic bonds polar covalent, then is Cs-F really the more polar bond?

Comment: Yes. Polarity is the existence of a dipole in a molecule. Here in polar covalent bond, the charge on either centers is very less compared to the charge on the centers in the ionic compound.

Comment: The electrostatic force here in ionic compound is solely responsible for the charge on the centers. A complete charge transfer takes place between the two centers in a ionic compound. Hence we write it as Cs+ and F-. But in polar covalent bonds, the C-F where C has partial positive charge and F has same amount of partial negative charge. But it's not equal to single unit of electron charge. Is it clear?